# Python subprocess crashing with exit code -9

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am executing a subprocess like this:

`process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env)` where `env` just contains some environment variables.

Afterwards, I try to get the output from the subprocess by doing this:

```
 output = process.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
 exit_code = process.returncode
```

and I find that my subprocess exit code is `-9`, which I am assuming the subprocess was forcefully killed. This usually crashes during a memory-heavy step, is there some resource limit on how much memory a subprocess can use? I'm running this in ECS (docker) on a ec2 instance and I know subprocess has more than enough memory to use.

Comment: Maybe check your rlimits? https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html

Comment: What command are you running? It will be helpful to know to help further.

Comment: @user2357112 is there a way i can pass unlimited resources to my subprocess using `rlimits`?

Comment: The amount of memory limited by the Unix `rlimit` mechanism normally defaults to unlimited. I have no experience with Amazon EC2 but would be surprised if it imposed a limit. And, yes, an exit value of -9 means the process was killed by SIGKILL. But there are many reasons that can occur. And I am skeptical of your assertion that the "ec2 instance running this subprocess has more than enough memory." What can be asserted without evidence can be dismissed out of hand.

Comment: @KurtisRader i tracked the memory usage on my instance and never exceeded 3%

Comment: Did the OOM killer kill your process? You can check with `dmesg -T | egrep -i 'killed process'`

Comment: Assuming the OS kernel sent SIGKILL (rather than a user process) then it is almost a certainty the system was in an OOM (out of memory) condition.

Comment: I'm able to run the script locally (my machine has only 32 GB of memory) but on my EC2 instance with 128 GB it still crashes. Maybe I need to explicitly tell the subprocess to have infinite resources?